# Excel Interop Range.BorderAround2 gives 0x80020003

Tags: c#, office-interop

I realise this means that this method is unsupported on the target machine, so that's fine, but how else can I get the same functionality?

If I use `Range.Borders.LineStyle` and `Range.Borders.Weight` then it doesn't put a border *around* the range, it will put borders around every individual cell inside the range (like a grid), which is not what I need.

The target machines use Office 2007. All other Office Interop code in my project works fine, just this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
sheet.Range["A1:D6"].BorderAround();
```

Comment: I don't have `Range.BorderAround()`, only `Range.BorderAround2()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this it should work.

```
sheet.Range["A1:D6", Type.Missing].BorderAround();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
Excel.Application nouveau_excel = new Excel.Application();
nouveau_excel.get_Range("A1:K3").BorderAround(Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous, Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlThick, Excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic, Color.Red);
```